# What can be the meaning of a word and a number?

Tags: rebus

```
 Stand     

 - - - - - -

 0_2345
```

Given above is a block that contains a word "stand" and a number "0_2345".

What does the block say?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most probable answer is:

> No 'one' under stand(s)

Comment: I think its the last one

Comment: Another clever pun... :) plus one's all round.